# Determine the memory usage in actual server through its header response size

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, http, google-cloud-storage, openstack

I have a log traces file from a server, there is a field header response size for a requests lets say 4585 etc, is there any relationship between the response size and the actual memory size in the server to generate this response?? I need to know the real size of a request when it processes it in the server, and after finish process, it generates response size, any idea or calculation method will be highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine memory usage on the server from the response size.

The (hypothetical) way to determine memory usage for a request would be to directly measure it in the server's request handling code.  But even that is difficult because it would be difficult the memory used by each request from other things.  It would only be feasible if your server processed (strictly) one request at a time.